# Is there a way to change existing JavaScript using a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm writing a Firefox extension to make a dynamic web app more accessible (applying ARIA roles, alt text for images, etc.) and I was wondering: is it possible to change the contents of existing JavaScript from the extension?  I was previously using the GreaseMonkey add-on to do something like this:

```
SomeObjectTheyCreated.Method = function(text){
    // My code here.
};
```

But the "GreaseMonkey compiler" is out of date and causes more trouble then it's worth, so I've got a ton of homework to do just learning to use this old-fashioned SDK (a command prompt, really? lol).  :)

All joking aside though, when I try to do something like the code above, the command prompt gives me the error "SomeObjectTheyCreated is undefined".  This makes sense, of course, because I didn't define it in the extension.  So what I'm wondering is, is there another way to sort of "re-define" scripts on the page?  Thanks. :)

Comment: To change the js file, you need access to the server where it is stored and served from.

Comment: Well that much I knew (for standard JavaScript), but for an extension...?

Comment: Sorry that was a bit rude.  But if I had access to the server, I would just login to the server and change what I wanted.  For a Firefox extension though, I thought we were just writing more JS on top of theirs (the term they use for this is "content script" and/or "page mod").

Comment: I have to be sorry for being nit-picky on the term "change". There are basically two ways to approach this: a) inject a script in the page that mutates the environment (including js objects defined by the page scripts) - the "greasemonkey" way. You need to know when to inject, and how to mutate. b) modify the loaded page scripts on the fly. rather complicated and errorprone, but possibly necessary.